# Regex to catch commands recursively

Tags: regex

I would like to capture my commands with *dynamic* group matching...
I'm not familiar with regex but it maybe requires a recursive group. Still, I don't understand the syntax.

```
some command content;some other command;another one
```

my groups would be any character between `;`.

Here's my attempt at the code, but it only works for the first two groups:

```
(.+)[;]*(.*)
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: If you are using a programming language you might split your string on a semicolon.

Comment: c++, it's kinda annoying to split..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be overthinking this: `[^;]+` will give you all parts of the string between semicolons. No need for recursion.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/U05Fmy/1).

Comment: idea to get all matches in c++?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this 
    (.+);*

or

```
(.+)(;*)(.*)
```

Comment: This will capture the whole string in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like it:

```
const text = 'some command content;some other command; another one;'

const regex = '/[\s\S]*;/gi'
console.log(text.match(regex))
```

The output would be: 
[ 'some command content;some other command; another one;' ]

[\s|s]*  ->  \s matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and new lines). \S is 
             negated \s. (*) It  means the occurrence must appear zero or more times.

;       -> symbol ';' must be included.